# constexpr won't work using Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2013 CTP (CTP_Nov2013)

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, constexpr

I'm trying to implement a compile-time hash algorithm using constexpr. I Downloaded Nov 2013 CTP because it has supported for constexpr but thats a lie...

```
#define hashCharacter(T, J)         (((T >> 0x0D) | (T << 0x13)) + J)

unsigned long constexpr GetHashCompile(const char * asSource, unsigned long asValue = 0)
{
return asSource[0] == '\0'
    ? asValue
    : GetHashCompile(asSource + 1, hashCharacter(asValue, asSource[0]));
} 

int main(int a, char ** b)
{
    const auto value = GetHashCompile("Hello from compiler");
    printf("%d", value);
}
```

GetHashCompile will not be generated at compile-time rather than runtime. How could i acomplish the above code using Visual Studio?. The same code works perfecly using GCC or CLANG.

Comment: apparently string literal parameters aren't accepted by this compiler

Comment: Try `constexpr auto value = GetHashCompile("Hello from compiler");` which actually requires evaluation at compile time.

Comment: Won't work neither, now outputs a compilation error. Says the value is a not constant and cannot be calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the November 2013 CTP does not claim to fully support `constexpr`, but only claims to have a partial support for `constexpr`. The [features list](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/02/c-11-14-core-language-features-in-vs-2013-and-the-nov-2013-ctp.aspx) explicitely tells that `constexpr` is not supported for member functions and for arrays. Since string literals are a kind of array, they are not supported either:

> The CTP supports C++11 `constexpr`, except for member functions. (Another limitation is that arrays aren't supported.) Also, it doesn't support C++14's extended `constexpr` rules.